# When to use an array with a maximum and when to malloc

Tags: c, arrays

When writing a project in C, I'm always conflicted whether to use an array with a predefined length with the maximum possible values, or create a dynamic array with the real length of the data.

```
int a1[MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_VALUES];

int *a2;  // will be malloced according to the data length
```

I understand that the `a1` will waste space if the length of the data is smaller than the maximum, while `a2` is harder to manage.

What are the rules when to use each method? How to choose?

Comment: There are no hard rules. Use a1 when it makes sense, use a2 where that solution makes sense. Avoid large arrays on stack, and remember that malloc() has memory overhead too. 

I prefer a1 when max size is well defined, like for names, adresses, URIs and such. Less hassle to work with. Personally, I often define a struct name_t {char val[NAME_MAX + 1]; }; along with some inline functions to work on the name_t. This way it's harder to create accidental bugs mixing up different string types (name_t array_t, uri_t, whatever_t) Also, functions can return name_t objects, which can be handy.

Comment: If the max value is known (fixed) and it is not too big, you can use static array. In most cases the max value is hypothetical and people choose value which is "impossible" to be reached.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard rules, but any automatic variable like "int a1[1000]" will take space on the stack, and any allocated space will take space on the heap.

Usually, the stack have a limited space (on linux, you can get it with "ulimit -s"), and the heap is, approximatively, your RAM.

It's up to you to know if you think your program will take unecessary stack space, and it's not rare to have to use "int *a2" instead of "int a1[MAX]" only because "MAX" is too huge.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be *"It depends"*.
It depends on a lot of factors and use-cases. Being someone who works on low memory footprint microcontrollers, I am more of in favor of static memory allocation.

There are no hard-n-fast rules, but if you are developing something for a smaller memory footprint platform, then you might have an idea of worst-case memory you need. Unless you don't have an approximated memory budget, the whole dynamic memory allocation case is arguable.
It is believed that, typically, for a small (small as in a limited-memory footprint) embedded system, its always *safer* to go with a static memory allocation than a dynamic one because, the trade-offs aren't worth it. Such that, you'd have to care about how much memory is being allocated dynamically, is there a chance of memory leakage since a typical C/C++ based system wouldn't have a mechanism like garbage collector. Think of a case when the systems fails to allocate the requested width of memory? There comes an additional error handling. Embedded systems (well, most of them if not all) have a fixed, anticipated memory requirement.

It might be interpreted in favor of static memory allocation that being in control of memory is a better way going ahead. Whereas, there comes a different perspective that with it the CPU takes the time to perform the dynamic allocation de-allocation, it adds overheads nonetheless. That is an added problem for a real-time system for an example as typical real-time systems usually comes without a dedicated memory management unit. The common-most problem with dynamic memory allocation is the fragmentation of memory. Fragmentation on smaller memory footprint is a different ghost altogather.

Consider this w.r.t dynamic memory allocation,
Lets say, the heap is 1024 bytes wide.

With no memory allocated yet: Available memory: 1024 bytes.

```
 ______________________________________________________________
|                                                              |
|                                                              |
|______________________________________________________________|
|<---------------------------- Heap -------------------------->|
```

I successfully `malloc` 200 Bytes for an array `arr200`.

```
 ______________________________________________________________
|              |                                               |
|    arr200    |                                               |
|______________|_______________________________________________|
|<---------------------------- Heap -------------------------->|
```

Now, available memory: 1024 bytes. I successfully `malloc` another 400 Bytes for an array `arr400`, assuming that it started from 400th location of 1024 Bytes.

```
 ______________________________________________________________
|              |            |                      |           |
|    arr200    |            |        arr400        |           |
|______________|____________|______________________|___________|
|<---------------------------- Heap -------------------------->|
```

Now, available memory: 424 bytes. But my next `malloc` would yield me upto 224 bytes at the most and we are doomed despite the precise memory approximation while designing the solution, we are doomed!